# "en passer par là" vs "en arriver là": Do they carry any nuance in this metaphorical context?

Tags: sens, usage

I just said in conversation:

> Je sais ce qu’il en coûte de recourir à cette méthode. Si vraiment on doit **en passer par là**, on pourrait peut-être au moins faire ...

I wonder in hindsight if I could have said "en arriver là" interchangeably. Or do these two carry any nuance here?

> Je sais ce qu’il en coûte de recourir à cette méthode. Si vraiment on doit **en arriver là**, on pourrait peut-être au moins faire ...

Usually, "passer par" and "arriver" denote  two different actions, of course, but in this specific (metaphorical) context, I wonder if  we really need to make a distinction between the two? After all, they both centre around the idea that "if we have to ***resort to that***".

Answer (score 2):

I'd say there is a nuance:
"En passer par là" implies that you need to go through something unpleasant to achieve a goal.
'En arriver là" implies that you have to resort to some drastic measure to achieve  a goal.
A common variation of "en arriver là" is "en arriver à de telles extrémités" but in this case the drastic measure aforementioned is already known to your interlocutor.

Comment: Interesting. So the focus is on "unpleasantness" vs "extremity"?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah..

Comment: En passer par lá is not always unpleasant.

Comment: @Lambie only when you are masochist. The phrase *(En) passer par là* means "endure a hardship".

Comment: Mais oui, **je le sais**. Je suis interprète, pardi. Mais passer par lá n'est pas toujours négatif. It is not endure a hardship, cela n'est pas le bon registre. C'est: **to go through something, an experience, to experience something**: D'autant plus que je l'avais dit lá haut.

Comment: La locution ***en** passer par là* indique **toujours** une contrainte. Cette locution (avec *en*) est d'un registre soutenu.

Comment: @jlliagre Pour traduire EN, il faut pouvoir décerner ce qui précède. le EN a toujours un sens précis donné par la situation du discours. Ici, on a dit que "you have to go through an unpleasant situation to achieve a goal". C'est faux. En tout cas, j'ai mis la traduction notionnelle que vous semblez ignorer. Alors, je passe....cette réponse ne traduit pas les expressions du tout. Il n'y a pas du nuance entre elles; elles sont complètement différentes.

Comment: Littré dit "en passer par" "se résigner, se soumettre". La connotation négative est assez forte, il me semble...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an André Gide excerpt from *Retour de l'U.R.S.S, Retouches à mon retour de l'U.R.S.S.* that shows the nuance is slight but exists between both expressions.

> Car pour eux il ne s'agit pas seulement de montrer comment on en est arrivé là (ce qui est, somme toute, assez facile à comprendre) mais de prouver qu'on a raison **d'en arriver là**, **ou du moins d'en passer par là**, d'abord et en attendant mieux...

However, in your particular sentence, both idioms are close enough for being equally usable.

Comment: So in the sentence I said, would you use "en passer par là" and "en arriver là" more or less interchangeably *in practice*?

Comment: In my experience, these locutions are typically used towards desobeying children. "S'il faut en arriver là, tu seras privé de dessert" or "s'il faut en passer par là, je vais te priver de dessert". So yes, there's a nuance that is reflected in the fact that an active proposition fits better with "en passer par là" whereas a passive one fits better with "en arriver là", but at the end of the day, what is conveyed is very similar.

Comment: @QuentinRuyant So I see your opinion on their interchangeability is the same as jlliagre's. PapaPoule pointed this out too, but I find this "*active vs passive*" difference convincing indeed. It's beyond me why Lambie insists on comparing the *literal* difference in physical movement between "arriver" and "passer par" whereas we are all discussing the nuances perceived in their metaphorical usage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69588/discussion-between-lambie-and-jlliagre).